# Can't use internationalization plugin i18n with Pinia Store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```js
import { useToast } from "vue-toastification";
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

export default function useToastMsg(message, type) {

  const { t } = useI18n();
  const toast = useToast()

  if (type == "success") {
    return toast.success(t(`${message}`))
  } else if (type == "error") {
    return toast.error(t(`${message}`))
  }

}
```

I am trying to use this function in the store after action has taken place.
store.js
`import useToast from "@/composables/toast"`

in action function:

`useToast("submit", "success")`

error message:
`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Must be called at the top of a` setup `function`

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 20):

This gave me some headache.
But eventually I did came up with a supper simple solution.

Step one:
Initialise i18n like this:

```js
/* /utils/i18n.ts */

import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
import messages from 'src/i18n';

const instance = createI18n({
    locale: 'en-US',
    messages,
});

export default instance;

export const i18n = instance.global;
```

Step 2:
Add above i18n instance to your Vue app like this:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import i18nInstance from '/utils/i18n.ts'

const app = createApp({
  // something vue options here ...
})

app.use(i18nInstance)
app.mount('#app')
```

So this is your usual i18n setup so far.
Now, when you want to use it in pinia for example, you can do it like this:

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { i18n } from '/utils/i18n';

const useStore = defineStore({
  id: 'StoreApp',
  state: () => {},
  getters: {
    getSomeTranslatedString() => i18n.t('String to be translated')
  },
  actions: {}
});

export default useStore;
```

Answer (score 1):

`useI18n()` can only be used at the top of a `setup()` function because it requires using the Composition API's `inject()`.

A workaround is to pass in `$t()` to `useToastMsg()`:

```js
// composables/toast.js
export default function useToastMsg(t, message, type) {
  //...
  return toast.success(t(`${message}`))
}
```

```html
<template>
  <button @click="sayHello($t)">{{ $t('action.hello') }}</button>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from '@/store'
import { mapActions } from 'pinia'

export default defineComponent({
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(useStore, ['sayHello']),
  },
})
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-i18n-in-pinia-action?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 0):

in store define a variable that contains i18n instance and define a getter to access it:

```js
...
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { Composer } from 'vue-i18n'; // WHEN USING TYPESCRIPT
...
const useStore = defineStore('store', {
  state: () =>
    ({
      $i18n: {}, // <== HERE
      ...
    }),
  getters: {
    // JS VERSION
    i18n() {
      return this.$i18n.global;
    },
    // TS VERSION
    i18n(): Composer {
      return this.$i18n.global as Composer;
    },
  },
  actions: ....
})
```

somewhere, better during app initialization, after pinia creation, create i18n and then assign its instance:

```js
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
...
// init Pinia
const pinia = createPinia();
app.use(pinia);
const store = useStore();

// init i18n
const i18n = createI18n({...})

// assign instance
store.$i18n = i18n;
```

then everywhere in the store will be available the i18n instance:

```js
...
const useStore = defineStore('store', {
  state: ...
  getters: ...
  actions: {
    saySomething(): {
      toast.success(this.i18n.t('it works!')) // USE this.i18n
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, better to provide link to whole Vue app to store. It costs nothing, because it's just link to object.
For Vue 3.x it's [official way](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/plugins.html#introduction) - the property `app` is that link to you app and we can do same for Vue 2.x by pinia plugin

`src/main.js` Vue initialisation:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    i18n,
    router,
    pinia,

    // ... other Vue plugins

    beforeCreate() {
        // provide Vue to pinia context
        pinia.use((context: PiniaPluginContext) => {
            context.store.app = this;
        });
    },
    render: (h) => h(App),
});
```

`src/index.d.ts` let TypeScript know about this property:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import 'pinia';

declare module 'pinia' {
    export interface PiniaCustomProperties {
        // provide Vue instance to store
        app: Vue,
    }
}
```

Example - access from the pinia action:

```js
export const useLaunchStore = defineStore('launchStore', {
    // ... other properties like state, getters and e.t.c

    actions: {
        launch() {
            // access to router
            this.app.$router.push({ name: 'launch' });
            // access to i18n
            console.log('->', this.app.$t('actions.launch'));
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Nuxt 3, and for example would like to update the language when the store changes. You can watch the pinia state change and execute the `setLocale` (or anything else) in a component. Preferably one that is always there, such as `App.vue` or a layout (e.g. `layouts/default.vue`)

```js
// either App.vue or a layout (e.g. layouts/default.vue)

<script setup lang="ts">
const { setLocale } = useI18n();
const settingsStore = useSettingsStore();
const { languageSettings } = storeToRefs(settingsStore);

watch(
    () => languageSettings.value.languageCode,
    (value) => setLocale(value),
);

</script>
```

I found the other solutions to hacky/messy so this is much cleaner.